# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

Am very new to spring and JUnit. 
Am trying to run a simple JUnit test case for spring service class, but it fails and I get this exception.I didnt write any test yet, but trying to run through before implementing. 
Using tomcat v7.0.
And I dont think have any spring conflicting versions. Please help.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptor(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:126)
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptor(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:96)
at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveActiveProfiles(ContextLoaderUtils.java:499)
at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:722)
at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:656)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:119)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Where else do i need to check, if there are any conflicting spring jars in my project?
And my pom.xml file is:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>         
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are mixing Spring versions (4.0.2, 3.1.4 and 2.0.8) never mix versions of a framework that is trouble waiting to happen. Note `spring-dap` is now `spring-orm`. Move all versions to `4.0.5.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That method appeared in [that commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/979c4833847400a73519e14a3a082e676a6e004d), which seems to be 4.0.3+. Just update spring dependencies to the latest version.

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that you are mixing different versions of Spring, you are mixing (2.0.8, 3.1.4 and 4.0.2) in your project. That is trouble waiting to happen.

To prevent these kind of things there is now a so called ["bill of materials" POM](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-rc2-available) which you can import.

You need to add a dependencyManagement section to import the bom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now in  your dependencies you can remove the version and replace `spring-dao` with `spring-orm`. Added benefit is that all your spring-* dependencies will now be managed to the latest release and you only have a single location for your version number.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You could apply the same trick for Spring Data as that also has a [bom](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-releasetrain%7CCodd-SR2%7Cpom).

Comment: Agree! Caused by having different versions of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your old jars with new one's based on the spring-framework-bom.LATEST.VERSION.pom file.

That way, i had resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the target folder in my maven project and rebuilt the war and this problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63215379/9225032:

Just check all spring dependencies versions. All should be same or at least new. Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my spring-boot-starter-web and spring-web versions to the latest versions and I was able to get rid of this error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35167740)