# @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit4

I try run unit test for rest controller follow http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GreetingControllerTest {
    //body
}
```

For this class I always get error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)

I found that someone had similar error because he used few spring versions ([java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789271/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils))

But I think that I use newest libraries and it isn't problem. For reliability I attach my 'mvn dependency:tree' result

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-            web:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.190:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.28:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Edit:
Attached pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>team.pocket.lublin</groupId>
    <artifactId>pocket-lublin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: When do you get this error? In your IDE or when running from the command line?

Comment: After run test from IDE (InteliJ Idea 14 Community)

Comment: Make sure you only have the maven dependencies and haven't been messing around with adding dependencies/libraries to the classpath yourself.

Comment: Could you post your POM? (so that we can try to reproduce the error more easily)

Comment: M. Deinum many thanks! It looks like InteliJ IDEA remember old dependencies from maven, after delete and reimport, test run without problems.