# loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/Producer] threw load() exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web.xml

I have a problem with setting up spring context using Eclipse + tomcat 8. I have checked several "Hello world" spring manuals and do not understand what is going wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.drew.soa.jms.producer.controller" />

    <bean id="connFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="defaultDestination"
        class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="CONSUMER.QUEUE"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="JMSTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connFactory"></property>
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Producer</display-name>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

@Controller
public class ProducerController {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ProducerController.class.getName());
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String renderVendorPage(final Vendor vendor, final Model model) {
        logger.info("Rending index.jsp");
        return "index";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/vendoraction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processRequest(@ModelAttribute("vendor") final Vendor vendor, final Model model) {
        logger.info("Proccessing vendor object");
        final ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        return mv;
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vendor entry</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div><h2>Vendor Entry</h2></div>
        
        <div id="form">
            <form:form action="vendoraction" modelAttribute="vendor"></form:form>
            <fieldset><legend>Vendor information</legend></fieldset>
            <label for="vendorName">Vendor Name</label>
            <form:input path="vendorName"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have the following error in console:

```
04, 2015 1:09:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 WARN | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
груд. 04, 2015 1:09:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
груд. 04, 2015 1:09:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/Producer] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.searchWithFindSemantics(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:738)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:468)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:495)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)

ERROR | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
груд. 04, 2015 1:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
груд. 04, 2015 1:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcherServlet] in web application [/demotest] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.searchWithFindSemantics(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:738)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:468)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:203)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:206)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:495)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you share more log? Most of the time there's some more information before it really finally breaks. But the NoSuchMethod error suggests you might be missing a library in `WEB-INF/libs/`

Comment: I have added more logs. Create WEB-INF/libs/ and fill it with *.jar but error remains the same

Comment: Check your spring library versions - you might have a mix of versions there

Comment: i`m using <spring-framework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

Comment: Please check for real in web-inf/lib...

Comment: i have copied all dependencies from pom.xml manually in web-inf/lib.. same error

Comment: List all of WEB-INF/lib and tomcat/libs - I'm **very** sure, we'll find spring 3.2.x there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your classpath you have old Spring lib.

AnnotationUtils from 4.2.1 contains [rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.0.RELEASE_to_4.2.1.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#rethrowAnnotationConfigurationException-java.lang.Throwable-)

But in spring 3.2.5 - [no such method exists](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html).

As obviously 3.2 <= 4.2 your tomcat will pick up 3.2 library into classpath first - breaking your code.

Maven dependencies can be a bitch - I'm pretty sure somewhere you include that old version.

Comment: can you describe which jar you found (and maybe even: Which dependency caused wrong file to be included?)

Comment: nope( i have checked tomcat/libs, then delete all in WEB-INF/lib and copied all from tomcat(include tomcats libs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63215379/9225032:

Just check all spring dependencies versions: all should be same or at least new. Example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```