# Spring junit test not working

Tags: java, spring, junit

I've got a Spring (4.2.5) project with Java configuration classes. These work when running the project normally, but I can't get my tests to work. In the test below the `repo` is null.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { HibernateConfiguration.class })
public class TestTest {

    @Autowired
    private InstituteRepository repo;

    //some test
}
```

If I add the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation i get an exception

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:365)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.util.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:274)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:154)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT]

If I change the springframework dependecy version to 4.1.3, the test works. Do I need different configuration for 4.2.5? The `HibernateConfiguration` is the following

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "myapp.services" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("myapp.repositories")
@Import({ HSQLConfiguration.class, MySQLConfiguration.class })
public class HibernateConfiguration {
}
```

Where the `DataSource` and `Properties` are defined in both `HSQLConfiguration` and `MySQLConfiguration`, which is selected based on active profile.

[EDIT 2]

After more googling I found [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13708), and after checking my dependencies it appeared I had spring-core-4.1.9 under the maven dependencies and I hadn't included a dependency it in my POM. After adding the dependency I see the jar under the maven dependencies, but I get a build-path error:

```
Project 'myapp' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.1.9.RELEASE\spring-core-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar'
```

This is my POM file

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- spring data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.data.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring dep -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hsql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- I added this dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With the following properties

```
<properties>
    <project.version>0.1</project.version> 
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springframework.data.version>1.10.1.RELEASE</springframework.data.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
</properties>
```

[EDIT 3]

The build path problem seems to be Eclipse related, running from command line the test works!

Comment: Is your `dataSource` bean declared within the `HibernateConfiguration` class?

Comment: I fixed that mistake, but Spring 4.2.5 still doesn't work

Comment: Could you attach the maven dependency tree? Asking to see if the problem is related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789271/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils

Comment: I've added the pom and fixed a dependency, but something seems to be using the old dependency?

Comment: Could be, use mvn dependency:tree to see who is using the old dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is only on eclipse, you will fix it doing: Project->Clean right click on project: Maven->Update dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Runwith` annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { HibernateConfiguration.class })
public class TestTest {

    @Autowired
    private InstituteRepository repo;

    //some test
}
```

Comment: This was what caused the error in the first place, which was caused by having the wrong dependency version of spring-core