# Why I' m Getting Below SpringIntegration Exception while running my application with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

why I'm Getting below SpringIntegration Exception while running my application with spring boot, my SpringIntegration Version is '4.2.5.RELEASE' and spring boot version is '1.2.6.RELEASE'

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.DelegatingMetricsConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getRepeatableAnnotations(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at com.gap.mosaic.dcreceipt.integration.service.boot.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getRepeatableAnnotations(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.inspect(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.inspect(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:493)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isInJavaLangAnnotationPackage(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789271/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Integration 4.2.5.RELEASE and Spring Boot 1.2.6 poll different Spring Framework versions. You should be sure that the Core jars are in the same versions. For this purpose it is enough to follow with Boot dependency management and don't specify a version for Spring Integration.

And switch to the latest Spring Boot [1.3.3](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) finally :)!