# Spring MVC Junit test annotations

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller

Having this as a test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class RandomTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PlanController controller = new PlanController();

    @Mock
    Platforms platforms = new Platforms();

    @Mock
    PreparedPlans plans = new PreparedPlans();

    @Mock
    View mockView;
    MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setSingleView(mockView).build();

        //platform
        Platform p = new Platform();
        p.setTemplates(true);
        Mockito.when(platforms.getPlatformById(1)).thenReturn(p);
        Mockito.when(platforms.getPlatforms()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(p));

        //plans
        PreparedPlan pp = new PreparedPlan();
        Mockito.when(plans.getPlans()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(pp));

        //permissions ignore
        Mockito.when(Perm.hasPermission(null, "ADMIN")).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMvc() throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/plans"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("plans", "platforms"))
                .andExpect(view().name("admin/plans"))
                ;
    }

}
```

Using following dependiencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>



<!--    .............     TEST      ..................       -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I always get maven error related to @WebAppConfiguration annotation (probably) but even when running maven with --errors and --debug options I cannot see more details than this:

```
[ERROR] testMvc(controllers.RandomTest)  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   RandomTest.testMvc » NoSuchMethod org.springframework.core.annotation.Annotate...
```

I am really desperate at this point, searched everything cannot find reason why this would not work.

Comment: Looks like version mismatch of Spring.  Read this for more:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789271/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core-annotation-annotationutils

Comment: When one doesn't use Spring Boot and its starters he will encounter NoSuch* Exception virtually contantly, that's the one of its benefits.

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a look at the [BOM Concept](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) and start to use the spring framework bom files https://search.maven.org/search?q=spring-framework-bom which make your life much more easier...